# How to import maxmind database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I know there are similar questions to this, but I never found a solution to match my case.
so my problem is i have a large file like 130MB with .txt extension.
now I want to upload this file to mysql database.
now I have problem uploading this file it gets timeout, using phpmyadmin.
is there a good way to upload this file using php?
or is there any other way besides those?

Answer (score 1):

Access your server via the console (ssh, telnet, etc) and import the file using the native cli client load data syntax to import your file data:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Edit: updating answer based on comments.

Since you can't access mysql via a CLI, i would suggest uploading the text file via ftp, then making a quick php script to import the file via a simple db connect + insert statement..

also use `set_time_limit(0)` to ensure the script doesn't timeout while executing the query..

You'll also need to make sure you have enough ram available to load the file.

Comment: I couldn't connect to the putty ssh any other suggestion ?

Comment: mysqlimport --local will have similar effect to logging into the server.